# Can't include or require an absolute path

Tags: php, apache

Apache version on server: 2.2.26

PHP version on server: 5.5.9

I have a file called `admin_config.php` in a folder, which has an `.htaccess` file with `Deny from ALL` value.

From `index.php` (at `DOCUMENT_ROOT`) I'm trying to include this file with the following line:

```
include '/core/config/admin_config.php'
```

At home, this works fine. On my cloud server, this doesn't work (no error message). If I use `require` instead, I get an internal 500 error.

If I change the line to a relative path, it works:

```
include 'core/config/admin_config.php'
```

Why can't I set an absolute path here? Is this some bug on the server, or an error on my part

Comment: Is the file located in a folder called "core" ***at the root of the server's file system***?! More likely it's in a path like `/var/www/core/...`, no?

Comment: @deceze You're right. But doesn't `/` refer to the document root of the web server, and not the file system? I have many hyperlinks which address `/`, and they all point to `index.php`

Comment: No, it does not. PHP has in fact no real idea what URL it was requested with. There are an infinite number of possible URLs that may refer to one file. URLs are important for a web server and require a web server to make any sense. If all file paths would be resolved through the web server, that would drastically slow things down. You can also run PHP scripts from the command line, where no URLs or document roots are involved at all.

Comment: I understand it as context - (1)File system context or php code execution and (2) html or browser file fetch context. / for (1) means the computer file systems root and / for (2) means folder with your index file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths you give to `include` or `require` are paths on the *local filesystem*. They are not what you see in URLs to access your site. An absolute path starting with `/` is from the root of the filesystem. In Windows terms, `/foo` is `C:\foo\`. Relative paths like `foo/bar` are relative to the the `PATH` configuration variable, which depends on how your `PATH` is set up which also includes which PHP file was invoked.

It's typically not a good idea to use absolute paths, since those are likely different on different systems (as you are experiencing). On your local machine the site may live in `C:\core\...`, but on the server it'll be running in `/var/www/mysite/core/...`. `PATH`s can also be cumbersome to work with. The best is typically to use `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` magic constants to construct an absolute path relative to the current file (if that made sense):

```
require __DIR__ . '/some/folder/file.php`;
```

This includes the file `some/folder/file.php` relative to the file in which it is written.

Comment: I made the above example easier than what it actually is. I was really trying to include a file inside `core/config` to a file in `core/WebApp/View/View.php`. If I was to use `__DIR__` I'd have to go back a few directories using `../` - Is this what you're saying or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. The only other realistic option is to use `PATH`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php. But, again, since it's a global configuration this has proven somewhat cumbersome over time.