# Included php files wont work after moved files subfolder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have a problem with php include section. In order to fully explain the problem, I created a test page for you.

First I want to show the schema of the files to you. Also you can download the test files from this **[LINK](http://dosya.co/6s2s7b3n4aw9/appname.zip.html)** and you can test it online **[TEST LINK](http://www.duhovit.com/appname/)**

[image]

As you can see, there is a subfolder in the `htdocs` (root) file and all php files in there. Now I'll show you the php code within the file, respectively.

***appname/index.php***

```
<?php include_once 'includes/config.php';?>
<div class="callPage">Click Here</div>
<div id="testBox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var siteurl = '<?php echo $url;?>';
      $("body").on("click",".callPage", function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: siteurl+'content/test',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //Do something
            },
            complete:function(){
              //Do something 
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#testBox").html(response);
            }
            });
    });
     function LoadPage(){
       $.get(siteurl+'content/test', function(data) {
          $('#testBox').html(data);
       });
    }
    LoadPage(); 
  });
</script>
```

***appname/content/test.php***

```
<?php 
include_once 'includes/config.php';
echo $text.'</br>';
echo $worked.'</br>';
?>
```

***appname/includes/config.php***

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://localhost:8888/';
$text = 'Well Come! How are you today ?';
$worked = 'It is working :)';
?>
```

When you open the **[TEST LINK](http://www.duhovit.com/appname/)**, `LoadPage();` javascript function will call `test.php` in the content file and display it in `#testBox`. First you will not see anything in `#testBox` from `index.php` . Because `config.php` can not be included from `test.php` .

I know if I change this line `include_once 'includes/config.php';` from `test.php` like this `include_once '/appname/includes/config.php';` then problem will be fix.

But if the pages multiply and, I want to use the files in the root (htdocs or www) folder, I need to delete appname (subfolder name) => `include_once 'appname/includes/config.php';` from all files. It will be a big problem when these files multiply.

Actually the question is exactly:

> How can we include php files without specifying the full path to the include, when the application's path relative to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is variable or unknown and `include_path` cannot be reliably modified by all application users?

Comment: _define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/inc/inc.php');_ really doesn't include any file. The rest of question is unclear.

Comment: @panther Normaly including inc.php file but after LoadPage(); not include

Comment: @DevStud what exactly do you want to do with that define?

Comment: @madalinivascu I want to include `inc.php` file in `test.php` after ajax `LoadPage();`

Comment: Use Ajax load method instead php include. http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/

Comment: @DevStud read my answer below

Comment: @madalinivascu but if i use `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/inc.php";` then all echo working.

Comment: @panther you can test it the problem with this script. I have created it for you. Maybe you can understand the exact problem correctway. [Download Script Files](http://dosya.co/6s2s7b3n4aw9/appname.zip.html) After the download zip file just upload it in your htdocs or root folder. and test it. Check the developer console. and see the include problem.

Comment: @DevStud: SO really doesn't work in style _here is zip file, download it, run the app in your own server and debug it for me_. Sorry, not question for me.

Comment: @panther online test in my answer you check it online.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040867/476

Comment: @deceze If your answer helped , then I would not ask for your help.

Comment: I don't see any indication that you have tried it. Did you try it? How didn't it help?

Comment: Did you read my question exactly ? I am asking : _How can we include php files without specifying the full path to the include, when the application's path relative to the DOCUMENT_ROOT is variable or unknown and include_path cannot be reliably modified by all application users?_ I also readed your question and tryed most of answer here.

Comment: You're trying to include files based on absolute paths, either starting at the document root or based on include_paths. What my answer says is to include the files *relative to each other*. Because hopefully *that* relationship won't change, right?

Comment: @deceze you can test it your answer in demo page. Now i am using your answer on there and look at developer console then see

Comment: You're mixing up multiple issues. 1. Local file include paths, what my answer pertains to. 2. Externally visible URLs, what my answer has no bearing on. – On your test page `var siteurl` is empty, your local `include` does not work.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for attantion, unwittingly mistakenly deleted. So now my test.php using your answer. Check it please.

Comment: So what's the issue now? That `http://www.duhovit.com/appname/content/test` can't be loaded? Well, it's supposed to be called `http://www.duhovit.com/appname/content/test.php`, no?

Comment: @deceze You can see Warning and Fatal error from demo page http://www.duhovit.com/appname/

Comment: And what path are you *trying* to `include` there? I'm only seeing half of the picture!

Comment: @deceze I am trying to include config.php from includes folder. But i know solution. Just i need one or two `../../ ` or little bit more `../` . So, if i want to use this files from root(htdocs) folder then what should i do ? I need to delete all ../ from the included files ?

Comment: Well, yes, you need to write the correct relative path from your file to the other file. From `appname/index.php` to `appname/content/test.php` it's `__DIR__ . '/content/test.php`. From there to your `config.php` it's `__DIR__ . '/../includes/config.php`.

Comment: @deceze then if i move my all files from `appname/` to `root(htdocs)` then what should i do ?  I need to delete `/../` from `/../includes/config.php`

Comment: Unless you change the **relative position of the files to each other**, you don't need to change anything. If from `index.php` to `test.php` it's still `__DIR__ . '/content/test.php'`, you don't need to change anything. If, of course, you randomly throw files into random folders without any pattern, then there's nothing that'll help you.

Comment: You could write an autoloader which look in each possible directory. [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php]

Answer (score 7):

This is sometimes a problem with includes when you're not using the absolute path on the system.

**Explanation**

Depending on how PHP is running could affect the way `include`&`require` work, if PHP is running from inside the appname directory it will work fine if php is told it's running inside the appname directory via a connector it's fine. however, if PHP is run for example `www-data@/usr/bin/# php /var/www/somesite.com/htdocs/appname/index.php` the path can be broken.

**Fix**

if you use `define("FS_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));` as the first thing other than if ther is a namespace inside index.php you can then use `include FS_ROOT."/includes/config.php";` this means file paths are used from the root of the system so it gets evaluated to  `include "/var/www/somesite.com/htdocs/appname/index.php"`

**Why this differs**

This differs from ROOT_PATH as ROOT_PATH is sometimes set by PHP configuration by web hosts and this could be the problem. as the PHP execution path could be wrong casing the PHP host application to look in the wrong place for includes and requries.

This also means no `include` or `require` should ever be using `../` as you should know the path from your codebase.

**your appname/index.php**

```
<?php define("FS_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
include_once FS_ROOT.'includes/config.php';?>
<div class="callPage">Click Here</div>
<div id="testBox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var siteurl = '<?php echo $url;?>';
      $("body").on("click",".callPage", function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: siteurl+'content/test',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //Do something
            },
            complete:function(){
              //Do something 
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#testBox").html(response);
            }
            });
    });
     function LoadPage(){
       $.get(siteurl+'content/test', function(data) {
          $('#testBox').html(data);
       });
    }
    LoadPage(); 
  });
</script>
```

**your appname/content/test.php**

```
<?php 
# as this file is loaded directly and is not in the root directory
# we apend the dirname result with ../ so realpath can resolve the root directory for this site
define("FS_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."../"));
include_once FS_ROOT.'includes/config.php';
echo $text.'</br>';
echo $worked.'</br>';
?>
```

Ideally, you should go through a bootstrap and .htaccess so you don't have to change redefine the `FS_ROOT` in every file loaded.

you can do this by making sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled in apache

**create file `.htaccess` in appname folder**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php)$
RewriteRule .* bootstap.php [L]
```

**create `bootstrap.php`**

```
define("FS_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
include_once FS_ROOT.'includes/config.php';
if(file_exists(FS_ROOT.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){
    include(FS_ROOT.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}else{
    // 404
}
```

this means you don't require the include for the config as it's automaticly included before the script for that request is wanted this is just a base outline and is not secure (and could be easily exploited to reveal system files contents) I would highly recommend reading up on how to use MVC's and how they work it will give you a better understanding of loading files on demand and requiring files.

Comment: Very nice but I did not understand how to use your expression. Could you give me an example through my codes?

Comment: Added example for your code and demo of how it could be set up to not require `FS_ROOT` defined in different files and so your auto including the config as most files will require access to it. @Azzo

Comment: I got blank page, after test your answer. I did everything same.

Comment: A Blank Page means there is a PHP Error and your display errors are turned off use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` & `ini_set("display_errors", true)` at the top of the `bootstrap.php` or your 404 was triggered and doing nothing check the paths are correct by debugging a little I did say it was a rough outline.

Comment: @Azzo did you ever get this working I just noticed your ajax URL parameter is wrong `url: siteurl+'content/test',` should be `url: siteurl+'content/test.php',` Ajax requires the full file path unless you're using a `.htaccess` mod rewrite rule to alter the php file paths.

Answer (score -1):

The `ROOT_PATH` definition is OK. You could include the path after the definition like:

```
include ROOT_PATH;
```

Comment: Could you answer me a little more clearly, please? Thanks.

Comment: i have tested your code and i get some notice but echo are worked. 

`Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH' in /home/****/public_html/subfolder/theme/themes/files/contents/test.php on line 1`

Comment: As panther pointed out, the definition doesn't include any file although the path is correct. So all you need to do is include it.

Comment: problem is this, i am trying to include it. but i can't.

Comment: Did you keep `define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/inc/inc.php');` above `include ROOT_PATH;` ?

Comment: `define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/inc/inc.php');
include ROOT_PATH;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161115/discussion-between-phil-and-devstud).

Answer (score -1):

If the document file paths need to be dynamic you need to use a database. From what I understand you are planning to make the project bigger, and so you need a normalized database to minimize the amount of code written on the server and to keep your data consistent.

You need:

- a parent table for `filePaths`
- a parent table for `fileNames`
- a parent table for `akas`   <== This is because files may have same name in different folders
- a parent table for folders
- a mapping table to solve the `akas`-`fileNames`-`filePaths`-`folders` relationships.

I will show on an example from `MySQLi`.

With this code you create the tables in `MySQL console` or `phpmyadmin`:

```
// Create parent tables
create table `fileNames` 
(
    `fileName` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`fileName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table `fileAkas` 
(
    `aka` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`aka`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table `filePaths` 
(
    `filePath` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`filePath`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table `folderNames` 
(
    `folderName` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`folderName`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB;

// Create mapping table
create table `fileNames_x_fileAkas_x_filePaths_x_folderNames`
(
    `aka` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `fileName` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `filePath` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `folderName` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`aka`, `fileName`, `filePath`, `folderName`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`aka`) REFERENCES `fileAkas` (`aka`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`fileName`) REFERENCES `fileNames` (`fileName`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`filePath`) REFERENCES `filePaths` (`filePath`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`folderName`) REFERENCES `folderNames` (`folderName`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

While this piece of code is only to make sure you are not making `MyISAM` tables because `MyISAM` doesn't have relationship constraints:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Now make a `PHP` program to easily add/change the data. Use this as a separate program and upload it to the server only when you need it:

```
<?php
    // Database connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    // Function helper
    function testIfAddedAndInsert($colName, $tableName, $value, $con)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ".$colName." FROM ".$tableName." WHERE ".$colName."='".$value."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." (".$colName.") VALUES ('".$value."')");
    }

    // Call this to add new file
    function addNewFile($name, $aka, $path, $folderName, $con)
    {
         testIfAddedAndInsert('fileName', 'fileNames', $name, $con);
         testIfAddedAndInsert('fileAka', 'fileAkas', $aka, $con);
         testIfAddedAndInsert('filePath', 'filePaths', $path, $con);
         testIfAddedAndInsert('folderName', 'folderNames', $folderName, $con);
    }

    // Call this to change a file path
    function changeFilePath($aka, $path, $con)
    {
         testIfAddedAndInsert('filePath', 'filePaths', $path, $con));
         mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `fileNames_x_fileAkas_x_filePaths_x_folderNames` SET `filePath`= '".$path."' WHERE `fileAka`='".$fileAka."' ");
    }

    // Call this to change all paths of all files that belong to a certain folder
    function changeFolderPath($folderName, $path, $con)
    {
         testIfAddedAndInsert('folderPath', 'folderPaths', $folderPath, $con))
             mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `folderPaths` (`folderPath`) VALUES ('".$folderPath."')");
         mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `fileNames_x_fileAkas_x_filePaths_x_folderNames` SET `filePath`= '".$path."' WHERE `folderName`='".$folderName."' ");
    }

    // ...

    // You can make as many different functions as you want

    // To populate/change the database example:

    addNewFile('config.php', 'conf_PHP_IndexPage', './../conf/', 'conf', $con);

    // or change all the paths of the items in the folder (not counting subfolder items)
    changeFolderPath('conf', './../../../', $con);

    // You could use FOR loops with arrays to enter/change big chunks at a time
?>
```

Then, after populating your database with valid information, add this to every one of your `main PHP` files (the files that are including others):

```
<?php
    // Database connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    // Function returns path of file from database
    function returnPathToFile($fileAka, $con)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fileName, filePath FROM fileNames_x_fileAkas_x_filePaths_x_folderNames WHERE fileAka='".$fileAka."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            return $row[1].$row[0];
        }
        return '';
    }
?>
```

And then just call the function to get the result:

```
<?php
    $include = returnPathToFile('configFileForTheMainPage', $con);
    include_once($include);
?>
```

If any changes occur to the file paths it is easy to change their values, while not having to ever even open the files ever again (for that purpose).

Comment: Downvote: And where would you get your `$con` variable? There is still the same problem

Comment: Thank you for the downvote, he can add the connection (one line of code) to each php file.

Comment: I will re edit to include that piece of information, which I forgot to include from the beggining. Thanks.

Comment: Still has the same problem I suppose.. According to your code, if he need to change any mysql connection info, he would have to edit all of his files..

Comment: Well, yes, that is true, but since the path of  mysql servers is actually just (for example) `localhost` and there is no directories involved I guess that changing mysql servers or mysql info like username, etc. would be the only downside to this method. I simply don't see any better way of doing this since he said he wants his paths to be variable. I immediately ask myself what if he does this what if he does that. That's where the needed flexibility comes from.

Comment: Anyways, he never mentioned anything about changing MySQL servers in the future only possible changes in website directory structure.

Answer (score -2):

The Test.php is in content folder.
If you want to include config.php from includes folder, you must need to do it relatively, so you need to go one level upper.

```
include '../include/config.php';
```

This happening because you run the script standalone with ajax, and the folder structure is relative to the test.php.